# Entity Framework Code first mapping - Non foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I came up with following scenario today, where i find difficulty in configuring code first fluent mapping

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReferralCode { get; set; }
    public string ReferedByCode{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> ReferedEmployee { get; set; }

    public virtual  Employee ReferedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Each employee will be referred by some other employee, like that employee will have many referred employees. **The referral will be based on Employee *Code*** not on ID.

How to configure fluent mapping for this?

Comment: A couple of questions for clarification: Do you still want Id to be the primary key of Employee, or would it be acceptable to have ReferralCode be the primary key? Also, what unwanted consequences arise from using Id as the foreign key rather than ReferralCode?

Comment: I need Id want to be primay key. The current system have Referred by and referral code oly .so i want to use that oly

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to configure a navigation property to have its foreign key related to a column/property other than the primary key of the related entity.

Your options are:

1. Change the primary key to ReferralCode
2. Keep the primary key as Id and do the following:

   - Add a `ReferredById` column and [use this as the foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620#ForeignKey).
   - [Enable migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn579398) (if they aren't already enabled).
   - Add a migration for the addition of the `ReferredById` column and edit this so that it runs a SQL script in a call to the [`Sql()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to update the value in this new column on the basis of the existing `ReferredByCode` column.